# plotting graph using palmer penguins

Tags: r, ggplot2

trouble getting plots in this picture using palmer data in R:

Expected output:

[image: expected output]

My output:

[image: my output]

not sure what I am doing wrong, anything helps!

```r
ggplot(data = penguins)+
  geom_smooth(mapping = aes(x=flipper_length_mm, y=body_mass_g, linetype=sex,))+
  facet_wrap(~species)+
  labs(title = "Flipper length vs. Body mass",      y = "body mass (in kg)")+  
   scale_x_continuous(limits = c(180, 210), labels=c("18", "19", "20", "21"))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(3000,6000), labels=c("3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: It may be useful to add the name of the library the penguins database is from to the question so other users can access it and answer the question. In this case "palmerpenguins".

Comment: It's best to include output like error/warning messages as text rather than screenshots - more accessible ...

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is related to the choice of x scale. I have removed the two arguments which specify the scale in scale_x_continuous and let each subplots scale be selected automatically. Here I have set the labels automatically using the scales package and the label_comma function.

Manually setting the scales leads to the issue that the points for the Gentoo penguins aren't visible and so there is not enough data for geom_smooth to estimate a line. This means geom_smooth doesn't plot anything on this subplot.

I have made a couple of other improvements to the graph which have been commented below.

```r
library(palmerpenguins)
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

# Removed the NA values for the sex
ggplot(data = penguins %>% filter(!is.na(sex))) +
  
  geom_smooth(mapping = aes(x=flipper_length_mm, y=body_mass_g, linetype=sex))+
  
  # used free_x argument for the scales to ensure that the plots showed the relevant flipper lengths in each plot (these vary by penguin)
  facet_wrap(~species, scales = "free_x") +
  
  # Added a label for the x axis
  labs(title = "Flipper length vs. Body mass", y = "body mass (in kg)", x = "flipper length (in mm)") +

  # Replaced the argument for labels with an automated function that takes values to the nearest integer
  scale_x_continuous(labels = label_comma(accuracy = 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = label_comma(accuracy = 1))
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Please let me know if there's anything missing from my plot in response to your question.

Comment: nice. Maybe edit out the warnings about version number, masked objects for brevity?  Could also explain *why* manually setting the scale breaks things (i.e. it omits so many points for Gentoo that there aren't enough points left to do the computations for drawing a smooth line)

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker I have attempted to improve my answer following your advice.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be the presence of missing values in the data set. For instance, you are grouping by `linetype` of `sex` and

```
data(penguins, package = "palmerpenguins")

table(penguins$sex, useNA = "always")
#
#female   male   <NA> 
#   165    168     11
```

So use `na.omit` on the data.
The other problem is the x axis. I have made the scales to vary by species.

```
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(na.omit(penguins), aes(x = flipper_length_mm, y = body_mass_g, linetype = sex))  +
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x) +
  labs(
    title = "Flipper length vs. Body mass",
    x = "Flipper length (cm)",
    y = "body mass (in kg)"
  ) +  
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(180, 230, by = 10), labels = as.character(18:23)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(3000, 6000), labels=c("3", "4", "5", "6")) +
  facet_wrap(~species, scales = "free_x") +
  theme_bw()

p2 <- ggplot(na.omit(penguins), aes(x = flipper_length_mm, y = bill_length_mm, linetype = sex))  +
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x) +
  facet_wrap(~species, scales = "free_x") +
  labs(
    title = "Flipper length vs. Bill length",      
    x = "Flipper length (cm)",
    y = "Bill length (in cm)"
  ) +  
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(180, 230, by = 10), labels = as.character(18:23)) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = pretty(penguins$bill_length_mm), 
    labels = pretty(penguins$bill_length_mm)/10
  ) +
  theme_bw()

cowplot::plot_grid(p1, p2, nrow = 2, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with scale-extension and without dropping NAs? Haven't experimented but my guess is that the problem is the scale-limitation and *not* the NAs ... (I note that the other answer also does both NA-removal and scale-extension though ...)

Comment: @BenBolker Yes, I had tried it. It gives lots of warnings and a wrong graph.

Comment: Thanks for checking!